# python unboundLocalError why

Tags: python, scope

```
import os

def createFile():
    if os.path.exists("highscores.txt") == False:
        myFile = open("highscores.txt","w")
    myFile.close()

def inputInt():
    number = input(str("please input your score "))

    try:
        return int(number)
    except:
        print ("this is not an acceptable input, please try again")
        inputInt()

def addScore():

    name = input("Please enter the name you wish to add")
    score = inputInt()
    messages = "thank you"

    '''open the highscores line and read in all the lines to a list called scorelist.
    then close the file'''
    scoresFile = open("highscores.txt","r")
    scoresList = scoresFile.readlines()
    scoresFile.close()

    #check each line in the scoresList list
    for i in range(0,len(scoresList) ):

        #check to see if the name is in the line
        if name in scoresList[i]:

            #if it is then strip the name from the text. this should leave theb score
            tempscore = scoresList[i].replace(name,"")

            #if the score is higher then add it to the list
            if int(tempscore)<score:
                message = "Score updated"
                scoresList[i] = (name + str(score))

                #write the scores back to the file
                scoresFile = open("highscores.txt","w")
                for line in scoresList:
                    scoresFile.write(line + "\n")
                scoresFile.close()

                #no need to continue so break
                break
            else:
                #message as score too low
                message= "score too low. not updated"

    if message("Score updated"):
        message = "New score added"
        scoresFile = open("highscores.txt","a")
        scoresFile.write(name + str(score) + "\n")
        scoresFile.close()
    print (message) 

addScore()
```

Above is the code. The error shown is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Computer Science\python code\highScores\highscores1.py", line 66, in <module>
addScore()
File "E:\Computer Science\python code\highScores\highscores1.py", line 60, in addScore
File "E:\Computer Science\python code\highScores\highscores1.py", line 60, in addScore

    if message("Score updated"):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'message' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Add more details to your question explaining your code and how you got the error instead of just code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) You are referring to `message` which is undefined when no `name`s are found in `scoresList[i]`. Put a

```
message = ""
```

line before your `for` loop. I don't know your actual intent, so this will make the error go away but check if the logic is still correct.

(2) You are doing the comparison incorrectly. You should write

```
if message == "Score updated":
```

instead of

```
if message("Score updated"):
```

Comment: Also on the last two lines:
`if message("Score updated"):`
`    message = "New score added"`

I'm assuming you want to have `message == 'Score updated'`